# Function test with rounding to one decimal place showing error even with correct answers?

Tags: javascript, function, math, decimal, rounding

My function is to either input a Fahrenheit and output the conversion to Celsius or input Celsius and output the conversion to Fahrenheit. My test challenges that I round whatever result to the first decimal, which I've done correctly. However my test says otherwise, I'm using 'Jasmine' to test the code. Here is what I've got.

```
const ftoc = function(fahr) {
  let input = fahr;
  if (typeof fahr === 'number'){
  let result = (fahr - 32) * 5/9;
  if (Number.isInteger(result) === false) {
    return result.toFixed(1);
  } else {return result}
  }
}

const ctof = function(celc) {
  let input = celc;
  if (typeof input === 'number') {
    let result = celc * (9/5) + 32;
    if (Number.isInteger(result) === false) {
    return result.toFixed(1);
    } else {return result}
  }
}

module.exports = {
  ftoc,
  ctof
}
```

and here are the tests

```
const {ftoc, ctof} = require('./tempConversion')

describe('ftoc', function() {
  it('works', function() {
    expect(ftoc(32)).toEqual(0);
  });
  it('rounds to 1 decimal', function() {
    expect(ftoc(100)).toEqual(37.8);
  });
  it('works with negatives', function() {
    expect(ftoc(-100)).toEqual(-73.3);
  });
});

describe('ctof', function() {
  it('works', function() {
    expect(ctof(0)).toEqual(32);
  });
  it('rounds to 1 decimal', function() {
    expect(ctof(73.2)).toEqual(163.8);
  });
  it('works with negatives', function() {
    expect(ctof(-10)).toEqual(14);
  });
});
```

My errors would be as follows:
Expected '163.8' to equal 163.8.
Expected '37.8' to equal 37.8.
Expected '-73.3' to equal 73.3.

Seems to be expecting some sort of extra period after the numerical result and I'm not sure why that is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions are returning a `string`, so just update your `expect` to:

```
expect(ftoc(100)).toEqual("37.8");
```

And it will work.

The reason is because `.toFixed` returns a `string` by default, as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).